# Story on tefillah

Tags: story-identification, hasidic-story

My grandfather told me a chassidic story about three Rabbis. The story goes as follows:

There once was a Rabbi who would go to his neareast forest to pray to G-d. When he went into the forest, he prayed, and G-d would answer his prayers. As soon as other Rabbis found out, they would also want to go to that forest, so Rabbi 2 went into the forest, but he did not know where to go exactly. So, he just went in, prayed to G-d and his prayers were answered.

Rabbi 3, however, did not know that he needed to go into the forest. He heard that the other Rabbis "went somewhere", but not that this referred to the forest. So, what did he do? He went into his house, prayed to G-d, and G-d answered his prayers.

The moral of the story seems that the only thing we need to do, is to "just" pray to Hashem, that is all He wants.

Does anyone know if this story is somewhat "famous" or attributed as an chassidic story and who said it?

Comment: As far as I know, it was invented by Eli Wiesel. It's quite well-known. I gathered that it was intended to capture the feeling of the Chassidic movement.

Comment: @Harel13 Nice. I found it. However, it says that he added unto that already excisting story, and it is a story about the Baal Shem Tov. So maybe there's a more authentic source dating back to the Baal Shem Tov?

Comment: The version I’ve heard is that this is about different generations- the first rabbi prays in the forest in a specific place, years later after hearing about this the second rabbi wants to follow suit but doesn’t know exactly where so he prays in the general forest, years later even more info is lost so that rabbi prays in his house, etc., the moral being as you said that even though we’re not as holy or knowledgeable as previous generations, we can still communicate with Gd through prayer

Comment: @CuriousYid isn't that exactly what is said above?